# How to sync Markers Comments between root Control Null & nested-in-comp-Null / Layer

Tags: after-effects, animation, after-effects-expressions, automation, after-effects-scripting

Hello Fellow VFX / Motion Designers,

I have spent a large amount of time going in circles trying to self-solve this one but time on the project is running low on time so I must ask the elder hive-mind for advice / assistance.

*I have a finalized marker-based-animation master composition that I need to template and build out.*

**The issue I am facing is that I cannot sync the 'root' Null layer's comments to the comments of their companion-nested-control Nulls.**

**There is 3 markers in total for each Nested Null - I only need to change the value of the middle / second ones**

Structure Example:

```
 # Master Comp Layers

  - [NULL] Outer Control A.1 > {Source for Null A.2}
   - Animation In Marker - Comment: "My Content"

  - [COMP] # Nested Animation A > [Hidden/Shiied for organization sake]
    - [NULL] Inner Control A.2 > {Target for Null A.1}
      - Timeline In Marker - Comment: [Blank]
      - Animation In Marker - Comment: "My Content"
      - Animation Out Marker - Comment: [Blank] or " "
```

I have tried a few of the free marker plugin's and available expressions to no avail - I think I'm missing something obvious here. They will copy and paste ad-hoc - but I need to setup a long-term link / sync here.

Is there a way to clone a layer's marker's via script? Or is there a plugin that can set this up for me?

*Full disclosure: Of course - I do have to keep project overhead fairly low so I'd prefer a native / free-plugin way to do this.*

Comment: So you want to copy the comments from the outer null to the second inner null?

Comment: Ideally - just not manually more then once and not every time I update. I have many nested compositions here and I'd prefer not to drill down through them all every single time to edit the source marker.


Edit: I've seen applications where marker comments dictate what marker is used from a sub-comp. 


Given marker comments are open for expression I was hoping there was a script or otherwise expression that I could apply that would automatically feed the comment text from my outer null to the inner nested null.


Edit 2: I'm sorry for formatting - I can't line break in the comment